# Merge multiple dictionaries into unified one using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

There is an object, lets call it instance_list that contains a dictionary with a word and its occurence (called feature_counts). I would like to combine all of those dictionaries into one.
So far, I have created a list comprehension like this

```
print("List:",[inst.feature_counts.items() for inst in self.instance_list])
```

and got the following list:

```
[dict_items([('deal', 1), ('lottery', 3)]), dict_items([('lottery', 2)]), dict_items([('deal', 1)]), dict_items([('green', 1), ('eggs', 1)])]
```

Expected output is this one:

```
{'deal':2,'lottery':5,'green':1,'eggs':1}
```

How do I transform my list comprehension into the final dict?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona)

Comment: Not exactly, but it provides useful hints for similar problems. Thanks for the link! I guess my question has already been answered by now in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `self.instance_list` is list of dictionaries, you can do:

```
out = {}
for inst in self.instance_list:
    for k, v in inst.items():
        out.setdefault(k, 0)
        out[k] += v

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'deal': 2, 'lottery': 5, 'green': 1, 'eggs': 1}
```